# Changing a range sliders min/max attributes and redraw dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, attributes, angularjs-directive

I want to create three range sliders with the HTML5 input type range. These sliders will we depended on each other, so that if I change the value of one it may change the min and/or max attribute(s) of another.

Lets say I have this data:

```
$scope.test = {
        slide1 : {
            min : 0,
            max : 100,
            step : 1,
            value : 50
        },
        slide2 : {
            min : 0,
            step : 1,
            value : 0
        },
        slide3 : {
            step : 1,
            value : 0
        }
    }
```

This should be represented on the view like this:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <input id="slide1" type="range" min={{test.slide1.min}} max={{test.slide1.max}} step={{test.slide1.step}} ng-model="test.slide1.value" value={{test.slide1.value}}>
    <input id="slide2" type="range" min={{test.slide2.min}} max={{test.slide1.value}} step={{test.slide2.step}} ng-model="test.slide2.value" value={{test.slide2.value}}>
    <input id="slide3" type="range" min={{test.slide2.value}} max={{test.slide1.value}} step={{test.slide3.step}} ng-model="test.slide3.value" value={{test.slide3.value}}>
</div>
```

So the first slide has a fixed min and max.

The 2nd one has a fixed min, but its max depends on the value from slider1.

Slider3 can only be altered between the value of slide2 and the value of slide1.

Well, if I change the sliders all of the attributes are changed and set to the correct value.

BUT: What not will happen is that the slider is also redrawn correctly. That only works if I go and change the value of slide2 and slide3. Set slide3 to any value and then change slide2. If you do so you'll see that slide3 is redrawn correctly so the thumb changes it position relative to the current value and given range. But changing slide1 does not show such effect. You will only see the changes when you start to change the value of slide2/3...

Is it possible to force the redraw of the range input element when the min/max attributes are changed on runtime?

Here is an example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UWChUywSpy64uvNbCHE0?p=preview

Comment: better create a jsfiddle/plunk with what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this by replacing that part of the dom with a new input range element with the desired values.  You can check it out at https://userbob.com/threeSliders.jsp   The max value of the bottom two sliders is dependent on the value selected on the top slider.